# How do I make windbg load clr.dll from a custom location?

Tags: windbg

I am starting windbg using the following command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64>windbg -i c:\tmp\Psscor4\amd64;c:\tmp\Psscor4\x86;c:\tmp;srv*E:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64>
```

Then I load a memory crash dump and inspect where did it load the clr.dll from:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\tmp\Memory.dmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Comment: 'Dump created by DbgHost. First chance exception 0XE0434352'
Symbol search path is: c:\tmp\Psscor4\amd64;c:\tmp\Psscor4\x86;c:\tmp;srv*E:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: c:\tmp\Psscor4\amd64;c:\tmp\Psscor4\x86;c:\tmp;srv*E:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (16 procs) Free x64
Product: Server, suite: Enterprise TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 6.1.7601.17965 (win7sp1_gdr.121004-0333)
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Mon Oct 14 13:45:55.000 2013 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 2:49:12.000
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
............................................................
Loading unloaded module list
..
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(5768.5db4): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first/second chance not available)
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x39:
000007fe`fd33bccd 0000            add     byte ptr [rax],al ds:00000000`3af07bb2=00
0:122> lm vm clr
start             end                 module name
000007fe`f9a70000 000007fe`fa3ce000   clr        (deferred)             
    Image path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Image name: clr.dll
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 09 00:10:25 2012 (4FFA59B1)
    CheckSum:         00959DDE
    ImageSize:        0095E000
    File version:     4.0.30319.17929
    Product version:  4.0.30319.17929
    File flags:       8 (Mask 3F) Private
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
0:122> ld clr
Symbols loaded for clr
0:122> lm vm clr
start             end                 module name
000007fe`f9a70000 000007fe`fa3ce000   clr        (pdb symbols)          e:\symbols\clr.pdb\D3D86782AEDD446F917F5D81FDFD3D252\clr.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: clr.dll
    Mapped memory image file: c:\tmp\clr.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Image name: clr.dll
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 09 00:10:25 2012 (4FFA59B1)
    CheckSum:         00959DDE
    ImageSize:        0095E000
    File version:     4.0.30319.17929
    Product version:  4.0.30319.17929
    File flags:       8 (Mask 3F) Private
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
0:122> .exepath
Executable image search path is: c:\tmp\Psscor4\amd64;c:\tmp\Psscor4\x86;c:\tmp;srv*E:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Expanded Executable image search path is: c:\tmp\psscor4\amd64;c:\tmp\psscor4\x86;c:\tmp;srv*e:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

So, my question is why does windbg insist on loading clr.dll from **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319** when both the image path and the symbol path direct to another location where sits the clr.dll that I truly need - **c:\tmp**?

Now, when I force loading of the symbols, then we can see this:

```
Loaded symbol image file: clr.dll
Mapped memory image file: c:\tmp\clr.dll
Image path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Image name: clr.dll
```

I do not like it. I want the image path to come from **c:\tmp** as well.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image path shows where debugee  (the process which were dumped) found the clr.dll.

Like it or not, it's noting you can do about it :-)

Comment: I get it. So it is not a problem, because the path shown as Image path corresponds to that recorded in the dump and has nothing to do with the path used to load clr.dll on the debugger machine, right?

Comment: I could hardly believe this, because there are commands for unloading and reloading, but it seems Kjell is right. Try: lm m mscorwks;
**** mscorwks is not loaded yet;
.loadby sos mscorwks;
!pe;
lm m mscorwks;
**** mscorwks is loaded now;
.reload /u mscorwks;
lm m mscorwks;
**** mscorwks is unloaded again;
.reload /s /v "D:\mscorwks.dll";